# VLC installation problem on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: vlc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwBqg.jpg

This is the error I am getting while installing VLC media player on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, kindly help me with it, because I want to run my videos and audios on Ubuntu as well

Comment: Can you open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install libtar0 libva1`?

Comment: Another item:  Can op open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get -f install` and post the output of that program into your question?

Comment: I just did it, it gave the following response, 

"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
"

Comment: Response; sudo apt-get install libtar0 libva1
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libva1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libtar0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtar0' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libva1' has no installation candidate
"

Comment: I am new to this medium so will be asking loads of questions,

Comment: possible duplicate of [VLC installation error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507525/vlc-installation-error)

Comment: Ask as many as you want, but please don't double post: http://askubuntu.com/q/507525/158442

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/509742/vlc-media-player-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

you should get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fonts-freefont-ttf libaacs0 libbasicusageenvironment0 libbluray1 libcddb2
  libcrystalhd3 libdvbpsi8 libebml4 libgnutls28 libgroupsock1 libhogweed2
  libiso9660-8 liblivemedia23 liblua5.2-0 libmatroska6 libpostproc52
  libproxy-tools libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian
  libsidplay2 libssh2-1 libtar0 libupnp6 libusageenvironment1 libva-x11-1
  libvcdinfo0 libvlc5 libvlccore7 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-randr0 vlc-data
  vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
Suggested packages:
  libbluray-bdj firmware-crystalhd gnutls-bin videolan-doc
Recommended packages:
  libdvdcss2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-freefont-ttf libaacs0 libbasicusageenvironment0 libbluray1 libcddb2
  libcrystalhd3 libdvbpsi8 libebml4 libgnutls28 libgroupsock1 libhogweed2
  libiso9660-8 liblivemedia23 liblua5.2-0 libmatroska6 libpostproc52
  libproxy-tools libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian
  libsidplay2 libssh2-1 libtar0 libupnp6 libusageenvironment1 libva-x11-1
  libvcdinfo0 libvlc5 libvlccore7 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-randr0 vlc vlc-data
  vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
0 upgraded, 36 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 63.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

That should get VLC installed.

If you still get an error instead, then please post back the output.

Also post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Another alternative, is to show us the content in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`:

open a command prompt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/
ls
```

Is your 14.04 install a fresh install, or was in an upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I removed Ubuntu 13 and installed 14.04 freshly

Comment: murtaza@murtaza-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
       Depends: libtar0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: what is listed inside? 
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @MurtazaMoiz: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/508153/edit) your question instead of posting multiple comments.

Comment: @AllGamer: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @saiarcot895 that is the actual solution to his original question, however his machine has an underlying problem with the sources that also needs to be addressed for the solution to work. The limitation of this "blog" like WebApp is not adequate for troubleshooting complex issues that does not fit the simple Q&A pattern.

Comment: @AllGamer: When asking for information, the standard is to write a comment asking for the information, and the OP edits the question to add in the requested information. A separate answer isn't created for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me assuming we are from Pakistan we might be facing the same problem

hit alt + f2 type additional drivers 
open the app,
this will open the window software & updates
go to the ubuntu software tab
below change the "download from", I selected the main server. 
close it

hit ctrl+alt+t (open the terminal)
type and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

download will begin if its done you can open it by typing:

```
vlc &
```

else run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

which I had to after that, run the

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Now it installed for me again to open it you can enter

```
vlc &
```

or simply go search it in the home menu

Answer (score 0):

Removing the vlc* packages and then installing vlc again seem to have solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc*
```

(***do note that the previous command will delete your configuration data for vlc***)

If it doesn't, I have also removed the videolan ppa from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/.

```
sudo rm videolan-master-daily-trusty.list
```