# VLC media player installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I have searched for many options on the Internet to install VLC media player on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr), but nothing is working for me.

How can I fix this problem?

Errors:

```
root@hiteshb-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~# apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libavcodec54 libavformat54 libchromaprint0 libmp3lame0 libvlc5 libvlccore7
  vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
Suggested packages:
  libchromaprint-tools python-acoustid videolan-doc
Recommended packages:
  libdvdcss2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libavcodec54 libavformat54 libchromaprint0 libmp3lame0 libvlc5 libvlccore7
  vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: try to type :  " sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade " before type " apt-get install vlc "

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of 2015-09-23, the latest VLC version for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) provided by this [repository is 2.2.1](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media).

Open a terminal and run (for 14.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

For other versions, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105587/how-to-update-vlc-to-the-latest-version/677450#677450).

Comment: Maybe you want to add the currently latest version provided there?

Answer (score 4):

To install VLC media player on Ubuntu you can try to open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If there are errors, you are welcome to paste the output so people will be able to help you.

You can try to disable IPv6 on your box. Sometimes it can be an issue. To disable IPv6, add the following to **/etc/sysctl.conf**:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After that open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo sysctl -p && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Try do the following:
`sudo apt-get update && apt-get install --fix-missing vlc`

Comment: Hey Alex, i tried your solution as well but didn't worked.

Comment: Check out my update, IPv6 could be an issue.

Comment: Same issue is generated, thanks for all your efforts, but still its giving same Error.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: i got following error "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

Comment: sudo apt-get --fix-missing
is indeed a good choice

Comment: Hello, I have tried to install from ubuntu softawre center but i am still not able to install VLC Player.I am getting error like Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lame/libmp3lame0_3.99.5+repack1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in 2015-1-8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/vlc-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```