# Software installation on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, offline, localrepository

How can I know what packages(i.e. *.deb) are needed to install a software (in terminal).

Suppose that I want to install VLC fully via terminal. If I run the following code then it will install the VLC along with other needed packages. It will download all required files and will store in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

How can I know what other packages(i.e. lib***.deb and like this) except the VLC(i.e. vlc_2.2.2-5_amd64.deb and like this vlc**.deb) are needed to completely install VLC(or any other software) before running this commands(without INTERNET)?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

The reason is because in my country the cost of Internet is high. So I want to check if the required files are present or not in my PC(i.e. previously downloaded or not! for any other software).

> the upper code is from [VLC media player installation on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509742/vlc-media-player-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `sudo apt depends <package name>` 
in your case `sudo apt depends vlc`

Comment: what you need to achive