# Unable to install apps on Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, vlc

It gives this error installing VLC and sort of same for the chrome too, can anybody please help?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
       Depends: libtar0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore7 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Thank You resolved it, had to change the download from server in software & updates.

Answer (score 0):

[VLC installation problem on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508153/vlc-installation-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/525597#525597)

This is worked for me

"

This worked for me assuming we are from Pakistan we might be facing the same problem

hit alt + f2 type additional drivers open the app, this will open the window software & updates go to the ubuntu software tab below change the "download from", I selected the main server. close it

hit ctrl+alt+t (open the terminal) type and enter:

sudo apt-get install vlc

download will begin if its done you can open it by typing:

vlc &

else run

sudo apt-get -f install

which I had to after that, run the

sudo apt-get install vlc

Now it installed for me again to open it you can enter

vlc &

or simply go search it in the home menu

Hope this helps.
"